# Mongo C# where condition automatic cast converting

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a LINQ query to select data from mongoDB. In mongoDB, EmpID is stored using different types like int16, int32, int64, string etc.
I always pass EmpID as string to a where condition. It is returning null when that EmpID is stored in NonString type. How to auto cast for these type of case ?

```
var query = from c in collection.AsQueryable<C>() where c[EmpID] == "123" select c;
```